Memory Leak in array operation in tensor flow
I am trying to make a marginal grid of (500,500,500) in tensorflow. Marginal means that I construct several (20, 500,500,500) grids marginalize them over axis=0, store this result into a list and then marginalize the resulting list. For instance:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


logrho_List = np.linspace(4.6989, 9.6987, 500)
logrho_List_partition = logrho_List.reshape((25,20))

example_array =  tf.random.uniform((500, 500, 500), dtype=tf.float32)

Result = [0]*25
pos_min = [0]*25

for i in range(0,25):
    iresult = [0]*20
    for j in range(0, 20):
        iresult[j] = (10**logrho_List_partition[i,j])*example_array
    
    iresult = tf.convert_to_tensor(iresult) 
     
    iresult = tf.exp( - iresult)
    
    Result[i] = tf.reduce_sum(iresult, axis = 0)
    
    del iresult
    

Result = tf.convert_to_tensor(Result)
Result = tf.reduce_sum(Result, axis = 0)

In my real problem result[j] is a (500,500,500) array of float32 generated by summing arrays of the same dimensions and multiplying them by numbers, which is executed by a normal python function. Simple arithmetic, but I want to keep this example simple.
It is driving me crazy the fact that this loop never finishes, by iteration 13 tensorflow crashes saying that it can't alocate enough memory for the calculation. Even though I am cleaning intermediate variables. In my script I keep track of how much memory the python process is consuming using
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
memory_used = process.memory_info().rss / (1024 ** 3)  
print(f"Memory used by process: {memory_used:.2f} GB")

and tensor flow crashes around 20 GB, even though I have 120 GB of Ram and a RTX A6000 48GB. I don't understand how can there be so much memory being consumed by this program.
I tried normal chat gpt suggestions like
os.environ['TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR'] = 'cuda_malloc_async'

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
except:
# Invalid device or cannot modify virtual devices once initialized.
    pass

at the start of the script and
 #Explicitly clear the session and collect garbage to free memory
 tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
 gc.collect()

at the end of every i-iteration but still does't work. I don't know if there is some other garbage that I should be collecting. I expect this loop to work, I am doing very simple array operations.
